# iOS - Cell Separators Don't Appear on UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

The cell separators on my table view do not appear in the iOS simulator. Here is the ViewController:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y2tM.png

Here are the warnings I have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b64B2.png

The custom segue is the one that I have when the user clicks on a cell in the table. I use a search display controller in the code for searching with the search bar, and displaying in the table view.

Here is what the iOS simulator shows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HHzB.png

The cell separators do appear when I click and drag the table, but not when it is not being interacted with.

I also include these lines in the code in an attempt to fix the problem:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

**EDIT:**

Here are the settings for the tableView:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RJNG.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWNZr.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5hcW.png

Comment: Will you post a picture of the settings for the tableview that you have in your storyboard?

Comment: When are you setting the separator style?

Comment: @rikkigibson At the end of the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: You are already setting your separator style in your storyboard, so there is no need to set it in your code in this case. You might try un-checking "Clip Subviews" in your settings. Sometimes that works for me.

Comment: @JeffLewis That didn't work :( Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Remove the seperator style line from your code & try to change the color of your seperator, then try & see

Answer (score 45, accepted):

iOS 11 simulators: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (`Pixel Accurate` option)

---

iOS 10 and below simulators: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (`100% scale` option)

---

**Physical device:** "it just works"

---

Also, you can show the separators by interacting with the `UITableView` (unless `scrolling`/`bouncing` is turned off).

Comment: I see this behavior with the iOS 9.1 simulator (iPhone 5s at least).  But never on a real device.

Comment: I can see it in 100% scale.